# get "path" of connected ids

Tags: lua

I'm just confusing myself over and over ...
I have the following table containing the information which id is connected to what other ids. And I need to find the "cheapest" connection from **ID1** to **ID2**

```lua
local ids = {
   [15] = {
      [18] = {
      },
      [23] = {
      },
      [24] = {
      },
   },
   [18] = {
      [15] = {
      },
      [21] = {
      },
      [50] = {
      },
      [248] = {
      },
      [330] = {
      },
      [378] = {
      },
      [914] = {

      },
      [1185] = {
      },
   },
   [21] = {
      [18] = {
      },
      [20] = {
      },
   },
   [248] = {
      [18] = {
      },
   },
}
```

The expected result is:

```lua
local table_path = {
   15,
   18,
   21,
}
```

Comment: Why are the elements ids[someID][connectedID] tables again?

Comment: those hold informations but that does not have to affect the function at all its just to mirror my table structure as it is what i will be using in the end. Most important is the fact that it is: **ids[someID][conncetedID] = Whatever_Value**

Comment: Ok, just be careful never to set that equal to nil or it is as if you remove it from the table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the cheapest connection should be the shortest, so what you want to do is a Breadth-first search. you need to save the path to each node additionally since this is what you want to get. Once you have found ID2 you can stop and take the path. Since this is Breadth-first, the first time you find ID2 is also guaranteed to be the shortest path.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

I just searched a bit more and found that:

[BFS algorithm using Lua that finds the shortest path between 2 nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465881/bfs-algorithm-using-lua-that-finds-the-shortest-path-between-2-nodes)

In the answer to this there is an implemented Breadth-first search in Lua. You could start from this and make changes for your use case if needed.

Comment: thanks a lot! that link was exactly what i needed!